# React Native this._handleLogin is not a function I have correct binding

Tags: react-native

I keep getting the following error with "this._handleLogin is not a function" and I do have the correct binding at least I believe so

It fails on the keyboard did hide

Here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            progress: 1,
            indeterminate: false
        });

        // Binds
        this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this);
        this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this);
        this._handleLogin = this._handleLogin.bind(this);
    }

_keyboardDidHide () {
        //alert('Keyboard Hidden');
        this._handleLogin();
    }

//  Removed the code to make everthing clear and shot 
_handleLogin() {
       ...
    }

<Form
                            ref='form'
                            type={user}
                            options={options}
                            value={this.state.value}
                            onChange={this._onChange}
                        />
                        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonLogin} onPress={this._handleLogin}>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonLoginText}>Login</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use arrow function or (bind in constructor) then you can call like :

```
_handleLogin = () => {
  // something
}

<TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonLogin} onPress={this._handleLogin}>
```

Comment: The was the first way I did it still gets the error, it's happing here 

_keyboardDidHide () {
        //alert('Keyboard Hidden');
        this._handleLogin();
    }

Comment: try with `this._handleLogin`

Comment: why are you binding it in `componentDidMount()`, it shouldn't be constructor? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks that was it, I wasn't paying attention

Comment: Welcome, fly ..if you use arrow function then no need to bind separately . Also you can accept as an answer if found useful

Answer (score 0):

Had the binding in the wrong place, was not paying attention.

Binds was in `componentDidMount()` and should have been in the constructor

Comment: Binds was in componentDidMount() and should have been in the constructor